# Full text search on substring in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to retrieve the data from the a database using `to_tsquery()` on the basis of text search. I am able to get the results for complete word search but not for the substring.

Example:

```
SELECT * FROM snp_gene_context
WHERE protein_name @@ to_tsquery('english','KIN') AND gene_dist='0';
```

I am able to get the rows containing the word 'KIN11' but I am unable to get rows containing 'Kinase'.

Comment: do a case-insensitive search.

Comment: can u explain how to do case insensitive search to_tsquery()? i searched with 'Kin' and 'kin' now and got same results as above mentioned.

Comment: Do you really need full text search for that? Why not just search for `'%kin%'`?

Comment: If you only interested in [prefix matching](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-textsearch.html#DATATYPE-TSQUERY), you can use `to_tsquery('kin:*')` -- for a more custom containment testing, you can use `like` / `ilike` with `pg_trgm` index (what [Tometzky](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30253701/1499698) already mentioned).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Full text search doesn't work on substrings — only words.

For indexed substring searches you'd need to use `pg_trgm` extension. There's a [good article about faster `like`/`ilike` searches using `pg_trgm` on *select * from depesz* blog](http://www.depesz.com/2011/02/19/waiting-for-9-1-faster-likeilike/). There's a trade-of though — much slower writes.