# PostgreSQL multiple substring search

Tags: javascript, arrays, postgresql

I want to fetch substrings from a GET-string in Javascript to pass them to a query on PostgreSQL.
I've tried already with PostgreSQL full text search, but ended up with the problem, that full text search only allows prefix matching ([Already described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30252903/full-text-search-on-substring-in-postgresql)).

So I'm looking to use the 'ILIKE ALL(array)' with an array of substrings with wildcards.

> SELECT * from parcels WHERE doc ilike
>   ALL(array['%substr1%','%substr2%', '%substr3%']);

I split up my GET-string in Javascript like this.

> var str = (GET()['search']).split ('+');

which gives me already an array of substrings.
How can I add a leading and trailing % to each substring with regEx?
Or is there a better way to archieve this?

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript you can use `map` for that:

```
var str = (GET()['search']).split('+').map(word => '%' + word + '%');
```

In ES5 compatible code:

```
var str = (GET()['search']).split('+').map(function (word) {
    return '%' + word + '%';
});
```

Comment: Works like a charm. I just had to encode the % to %25 and add ' as %27, so that my query could be send via GET. so: `var str = (GET()['search']).split('+').map(function (word) {
                  return '%27%25' + word + '%25%27';
                  });` does the job.  My Where-clause then is called via: `where: "doc ilike all(array["+str+"])",`

Comment: Ah, yes, you could in fact use `return encodeURIComponent("'%" + word + "%'")`, that way you leave the encoding to JavaScript, which will also escape special characters if they occur in the word itself. Although I notice that a quote is not regarded as special, so I am not sure why it would be a problem in your case.